# wp_login_url redirects me always to wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a specific site on my website which needs to be logged in.
So if I visit the page and I am not logged in, I want to redirected to `wp-login`and back to the page. But everything I am trying, I will always redirected to `wp-admin`

That is one of my failures:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', [ $this, 'redirect_to_login_page' ] );
```

```
public function redirect_to_login_page() {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/test' ) !== false ) {
            $login_url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', site_url( '/test' ), wp_login_url() );
            wp_redirect( $login_url );
            exit;
        }
    }
```

What can I do?

Comment: hi, just asking if you have op-cache enabled on server?  because of this many a times changes are not visible immediately. In that case restarting server or php-fpm resolves the issue.

Comment: Hi, sadly there is no cache active

Answer (score 0):

To generate the login URL with the desired redirect URL already included. Then, we're using `wp_redirect()` to redirect the user to the login page.

#### Try below code

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', [ $this, 'redirect_to_login_page' ] );

public function redirect_to_login_page() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/test' ) !== false ) {
        $login_url = wp_login_url( site_url( '/test' ) );
        wp_redirect( $login_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

If the issue still not fixed and you're being redirected to the wp-admin page instead of the login page, you might want to check your WordPress settings to make sure that the login URL is set correctly.